# Ajax if JSON value is null set to blank or n/a

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am retrieving some JSON data via AJAX and printing the values into an HTML table as listed below:

```
var page = $('#serviceload').val();

$.post('api/profileSearch.php', {
    page: page
}, function (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#tableBody').empty();
    var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
        return '<tr><td>' + item.COL1 + '</td><td>' + item.COL2 + '</td><td>' + item.COL3 + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#tableBody').html(htmlToInsert);
});
```

Using this method, I am able to print the values into a TABLE.

I want to be able to check if any of the JSON items are null, and if so, print N/A or just leave it blank.  Basically, I don't want to display null within the cell.

Now I know I can go into the database and just run a query that can take all the null values and make them blank.  I just need to be able to check for null values just in case. How do I do this?

Comment: Write like this inside the td `item.COL1 == null ? "N/A" : itemCOL1`?

Comment: alternative in concatenation `'<tr><td>'+ (item.COL1 || 'N/A') + ...`

Comment: I went ahead and cleared all the null values in the database and prevented any future null values from occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care about escaping text item.COL1 could have "<", ">" and "&"

```
function myTd(textData){
   return $('<td>').text(textData==null ? 'N/A' : textData);
}

var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item){
   return $('<tr>').append(myTd(item.COL1),myTd(item.COL2),myTd(item.COL3));
});

$('#tableBody').append(htmlToInsert);
```